Oracle SQL select ID where 3 condition share the same ID
My problem is this one I got a query that is like this:
SELECT ID FROM TABLE LEFT JOIN ANOTHERTABLE ON TABLE.ID=ANOTHERTABLE.ID WHERE TABLE.KEY='X' OR TABLE.KEY='Y' OR TABLE.KEY='Z';

When I play this query it will return more than one id... but 3 id are the same (because each condition pick it).
I need to select the only id that show up multiple times but without using count... Basically I need to select the only ID that will be select by condition 1, 2 and 3.
I don't really understand how to do it.
Do you know how?
EDIT.
I was able to find a really strange solution that works but if you can make it easier to read please do it...
SELECT PC_ID 
FROM A a
left join B b 
on a.EDI_ID = b.ID
WHERE b.key='X' AND b.value='some'
AND a.PC_ID in (
SELECT PC_ID  
FROM A a
left join B b
on a.EDI_ID = b.ID
where b.key='Y' AND b.value='something'
)
AND a.PC_ID in (
SELECT PC_ID  
FROM A a 
left join B b 
on a.EDI_ID = b.ID
where b.key='Z' AND b.value='thing'
)

Maybe after this edit it will be easier to help me.
EDIT2.
I have two tables.
My main table (B) contains three fields:
ID, KEY and VALUE
My table (A) contains two fields:
PC_ID (the id I want to select), EDI_ID (the id contained in the main table).
In my main table I am sure that by using key and value with 3 different values ​​(which are passed to me from the frontend) all the IDs of my main table will have a match in my table A (there will therefore be an EDI_ID for each ID). And in turn PC_ID corresponding to the EDI_ID can have many values ​​for each of the three conditions... but only one value will be the same for all three conditions.
So filtering in the main table (B) for key='X' value='condition1' I will get a series of ID....
This set of ID will always have a corresponding EDI_ID in table (A).
There will then be a series of PC_ID values ​​that correspond to each EDI_ID selected.
Same thing happens for the condition key='Y' value='condition2'
Same thing happens for the condition key='Z' value='condition3'
But all three of these selects will have only one PC_ID value in common, which is the one I want to select.
I hope it's clearer this way.
EDIT3.
I made a postgres example of the dataset + query
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/redSAVfixCHUE4zPu5aAkk/11
But like I said in the comment the 3rd query this only works on db fiddle (maybe a difference between oracle and postgres? I'm not sure...)
#this is working here but not working on my real dataset
SELECT A.PC_ID FROM A
INNER JOIN B AS bx ON A.EDI_ID = bx.ID AND bx.KEYV = 'X' AND bx.valuev='some'
INNER JOIN B AS byy ON A.EDI_ID = byy.ID AND byy.KEYV = 'Y' AND byy.valuev='something'
INNER JOIN B AS bz ON A.EDI_ID = bz.ID AND bz.KEYV = 'Z' AND bz.valuev='thing';

the example dataset should be right but I really cannot be 100% sure, I did not make the original dataset so this is still my own interpretation of it. I hope this is a good way for anybody with more skill than me to find out why and how.
FINAL EDIT.
I changed the dataset to actually fit what's inside my db:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/redSAVfixCHUE4zPu5aAkk/15
basically what I did wrong yesterday and the reason why the last one did not work on real data was that EDI_ID always change, while there can be more than one PC_ID that's the same (it was the opposite of what I did yesterday).
So no answer that I can use actually worked (not even the last one with LISTAGG).
If you can fix it with the new dataset I will accept the first with an answer that actually work and that's different than mine and that don't use COUNT.

@JonasMetzler Sorry I did another edit. I'm not really used to sql (I usually only do easy query, and most of the time I only work in Java). I will make an example dataset as soon as possible. Can you please see if the question is now clear?

@JonasMetzler I'm trying to make it... but for some reason the JensV query work on my example while it will not work on the real db, so I'm trying to understand what's different before I share it

@JonasMetzler I really don't undestand right now... this is my current result https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/redSAVfixCHUE4zPu5aAkk/11 but like I said in the comment the 3rd query did not work on my real data (not sure why)

If you have duplicate pc_id values then you can use:
SELECT a.pc_id
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b
       ON a.edi_id = b.id
WHERE  (b.key, b.value) IN (
         ('X', 'some'), ('Y', 'something'), ('Z', 'thing')
       )
GROUP BY a.pc_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.key) = 3

or, without using COUNT, you can use other aggregation functions:
SELECT a.pc_id
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b
       ON a.edi_id = b.id
WHERE  (b.key, b.value) IN (
         ('X', 'some'), ('Y', 'something'), ('Z', 'thing')
       )
GROUP BY a.pc_id
HAVING MAX(CASE b.key WHEN 'X' THEN 1 END) = 1
AND    MAX(CASE b.key WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) = 1
AND    MAX(CASE b.key WHEN 'Z' THEN 1 END) = 1

Or, from Oracle 12, MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT pc_id
FROM   (
  SELECT a.pc_id,
         b.key
  FROM   a
         INNER JOIN b
         ON a.edi_id = b.id
  WHERE  (b.key, b.value) IN (
           ('X', 'some'), ('Y', 'something'), ('Z', 'thing')
         )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY pc_id
  ORDER BY key
  PATTERN (x+ y+ z+)
  DEFINE x AS key = 'X',
         y AS key = 'Y',
         z AS key = 'Z'
)

Which, for your "final edit" sample data:
CREATE TABLE A (
  PC_ID INT,
  EDI_ID INT
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  ID INT,
  KEY VARCHAR(255),
  VALUE VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO A (PC_ID, EDI_ID) VALUES (100,10), (100,12), (100,13), (101,20), (102, 30), (103,40), (12, 50),(324, 120);

INSERT INTO B (ID, KEY, VALUE) VALUES
(10, 'X', 'some'),
(12, 'Y', 'something'),
(13, 'Z', 'thing'),
(20, 'Z', 'thing'),
(30, 'Z', 'thing'),
(40, 'Z', 'thing'),
(50, 'Z', 'thing'),
(120, 'NO', 'nothing to see');

All output:



PC_ID




100



fiddle

I tried your MATCH_RECOGNIZE answer and it only work if I remove the ORDER BY key. Do you know why? Still I will accept this answer since with a little tweak it worked on the real dataset

@LiefLayer You need to sort the values using ORDER BY for the pattern matching to work (otherwise you are testing against a random ordering and it is only coincidence that your data gets matched). Your example data has X, Y, Z which sort nicely into alphabetic order. If your real data has One, Two, Three instead of X, Y, Z then sorting those alphabetically would be One, Three, Two and you would need to match the pattern in the same order that the ORDER BY puts them into. fiddle

Let's call the tables A and B for simplicity.
If I understood the question correctly, you only want the rows of A if you find the three rows in B with the corresponding ID and the B rows have KEY X, Y and Z.
I'd join the B table three times, on ID and the corresponding KEY and then filter on WHERE to check if all three B rows are present:
SELECT A.ID FROM A
LEFT JOIN B AS bx ON A.ID = bx.ID AND bx.KEY = 'X'
LEFT JOIN B AS by ON A.ID = by.ID AND by.KEY = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN B AS bz ON A.ID = bz.ID AND bz.KEY = 'Z'
WHERE bx.ID IS NOT NULL AND by.ID IS NOT NULL AND bz.ID IS NOT NULL;

You could simplify this slightly by using an INNER JOIN which will filter out the rows where it couldn't find the corresponding B row, making the WHERE condition redundant:
SELECT A.ID FROM A
INNER JOIN B AS bx ON A.ID = bx.ID AND bx.KEY = 'X'
INNER JOIN B AS by ON A.ID = by.ID AND by.KEY = 'Y'
INNER JOIN B AS bz ON A.ID = bz.ID AND bz.KEY = 'Z';


Sorry but I'm not sure if I understand your solution and it does not work... Basically with my current query the first condition key='X' result in 1 id, key='Y' result in 1 id and finally key='Z' result in multiple id... if I put all them in OR I get 3 correct ids and multiple wrong one from the 3rd condition (but I could get multiple from key='X' and key='Y' too). I need the result to only contain one ID (don't worry about IS NOT NULL since it's a primarykey) the only one that I will get from all the condition at the same time.

that solution for some reason that I don't understand return empty value...

PS: I added a working example, still not that great

@LiefLayer a working example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nJ7nRGCbJhq9FT2UJFiGZp/0 it's postgres but that shouldn't really matter. If this doesn't do what you want, you need to provide an example dataset and the expected result, otherwise it's too unclear

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/redSAVfixCHUE4zPu5aAkk/11 here your query work, not sure if it's a postgres thing but on mine it did not work

I updated my dataset to actually be correct. You can find it in the FINAL EDIT at the end

You can use:
SELECT pc_id
FROM   a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   b
               WHERE  a.edi_id = b.id 
               AND    (b.key, b.value) IN (
                        ('X', 'some'), ('Y', 'something'), ('Z', 'thing')
                      )
               GROUP BY b.id
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.key) = 3)

or:
SELECT pc_id
FROM   a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   b
               WHERE  a.edi_id = b.id 
               AND    b.key = 'X'
               AND    b.value = 'some' )
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   b
               WHERE  a.edi_id = b.id 
               AND    b.key = 'Y'
               AND    b.value = 'something' )
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   b
               WHERE  a.edi_id = b.id 
               AND    b.key = 'Z'
               AND    b.value = 'thing' )

or, if you are using Oracle 12 or later:
SELECT pc_id
FROM   a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM   b
                        WHERE  (b.key, b.value) IN (
                                 ('X', 'some'), ('Y', 'something'), ('Z', 'thing')
                               )
                      )
                      MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
                        PARTITION BY id
                        ORDER BY key
                        PATTERN ( x+ y+ z+ )
                        DEFINE x AS key = 'X',
                               y AS key = 'Y',
                               z AS key = 'Z'
                      )
               WHERE  a.edi_id = id)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE A (PC_ID INT, EDI_ID INT);

CREATE TABLE B (ID INT, KEY VARCHAR(255), VALUE VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO A (PC_ID, EDI_ID) VALUES (100,10), (101,20), (102, 30), (103,40), (12, 50),(324, 120);

INSERT INTO B (ID, KEY, VALUE) VALUES
(10, 'X', 'some'),
(10, 'Y', 'something'),
(10, 'Z', 'thing'),
(20, 'Z', 'thing'),
(30, 'Z', 'thing'),
(40, 'Z', 'thing'),
(50, 'Z', 'thing'),
(120, 'NO', 'nothing to see');

All output:



PC_ID




100



fiddle

I will try this solution too tomorrow at this point. even in your own fiddle that use oracle JensV solution work (but it did not work on the real data for some strange reason). Still I want to try the EXISTS solution (maybe the most clean one). Like I said I should not use any COUNT solution. I'll upvote both of you for now, tomorrow I will decide what answer should I accept (right now I cannot access my working pc). Thank you.

@LiefLayer Using two SELECTs will be more efficient than using four so you really should consider why you have an (apparently arbitrary) restriction about using COUNT. I've added another solution that does not use COUNT.

I updated my dataset to actually be correct. You can find it in the FINAL EDIT at the end

You could use LISTAGG() analytic function to group your KEYV and VALUEV values and Inner Join them like below. There is no COUNT() of any kind and one Select from tables A and B:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    A (PC_ID, EDI_ID) AS
        ( Select 100, 10 From Dual Union All  
          Select 101, 20 From Dual Union All   
          Select 102, 30 From Dual Union All  
          Select 103, 40 From Dual Union All  
          Select  12, 50 From Dual Union All  
          Select 324, 120 From Dual 
        ),
    B (ID, KEYV, VALUEV) AS
        ( Select 10, 'X', 'some' From Dual Union All
          Select 10, 'Y', 'something' From Dual Union All
          Select 10, 'Z', 'thing' From Dual Union All
          Select 20, 'Z', 'thing' From Dual Union All
          Select 30, 'Z', 'thing' From Dual Union All
          Select 40, 'Z', 'thing' From Dual Union All
          Select 50, 'Z', 'thing' From Dual Union All
          Select 120, 'NO', 'nothing to see' From Dual 
        )

--      S Q L :
Select   a.*
From     A a
Inner Join ( Select   DISTINCT  ID, 
                          ',' || LISTAGG(Distinct KEYV, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By KEYV) Over(Partition By ID) || ',' "KEYS", 
                          ',' || LISTAGG(Distinct VALUEV, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By VALUEV) Over(Partition By ID) || ',' "VALS"
             From     B
           ) b ON(b.ID = a.EDI_ID And 
                  InStr(b.KEYS, ',X,') > 0 And InStr(b.KEYS, ',Y,') > 0 And InStr(b.KEYS, ',Z,') > 0 And
                  InStr(b.VALS, ',some,') > 0 And InStr(b.VALS, ',something,') > 0 And InStr(b.VALS, ',thing,') > 0 
                 )

/*    R e s u l t :
     PC_ID     EDI_ID
---------- ----------
       100         10     */ 

And if you can sort, concatinate and delimit (comma) your frontend provided parameters then you can change ON() clause like below:
... ...
               ON(b.ID = a.EDI_ID And 
                  b.KEYS = ',X,Y,Z,' And
                  b.VALS = ',some,something,thing,'
                 )

... the result would be the same.
NOTE: It is important that you use a delimiter before and after the lists (KEYS and VALS) as well as all your frontend values to avoid false comparisons like searching for 'thing' in 'some,something' which is true. This way you are searching for ',thing,' in ',some,something,' which is false.

I updated my dataset to actually be correct. You can find it in the FINAL EDIT at the end
